# resultLimit not working on getVirtualGuests with an objectFilter

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using URL https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json with resultLimit=0,100  with object filter of &objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"_=che01"}}}}  The REST API is ignoring the resultLimit and is returning more  all the virtual guest entries in the datacenter.  When did this change?

Comment: The filter and limit look good, filtering and limits on getHardware works as expected, and filtering with other fields work too, so just with the datacenter are broke, at this time, this not was fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

The result limit work well with mask, but with filter there are problems with this method, can open a ticket for this problem.

references:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/using-result-limits-softlayer-api/

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks/

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters/